# Android Native timer for bringing back the device to wake up mode?

Tags: android, timer, android-ndk

I want to launch a timer which will get fired when the timer gets expired when the device is in low power (sleep) mode.

Device only gets waked up (normal mode) either on hard ware event (pressing of power button) or any network activity (call or data packet receiving).

Is there any way to bring the device back to the normal mode with timers in the native layer of android?

I googled so much but not able to find a way. Tried using timer_create() as well. But its not getting fired when the device is in low power (sleep) mode.

Please let me know if anyone had already done on this part.

Actually precision required for me is in milliseconds and the AlarmManager with RTC_WAKEUP is in the application layer which is expiring after consider delay and also this is in the Java layer. (If I implement Jni it will make some overhead to the application as there are multiple timers which need to be run in sleep mode).

Answer (score 0):

To bring back the device up i think you can explore on these lines
1. PowerMangerService

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
    //..screen will stay on during this section..

    wl.release();
```

2. android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT value in the settings for screen time out.
3. Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF intents by PowerManagerService

Comment: If I want to wake up the device after an hour, it will drain the battery if I make screen display ON for so long time or even if I acquire the power wake lock.

Comment: your right , i was thinking on these lines 1. register for the intent 2. start your own timer on receive of this intent 3. check the system settings timeout value if needed  4. acquire the wake clock when u think you are ready ...

Comment: Appreciation for your effort :). The above thing is little bit complex even then Problem is who will send the broadcast intent :).